# Weird SELECT statement

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

Does anybody know what it means to have a space between `! =` in a where clause?

For instance:

```
Select ColA
From TableA
Where ColA.ID ! = ColB.ID ?
```

It is not entirely 'Not equal' operator in Postgres and I can't find reference to it on the internet.

Answer (score 2):

The `!` exclamation mark is the operator for factorial. So the expression

```
ColA.ID ! = ColB.ID
```

is evaluated as

```
(ColA.ID!) = ColB.ID
```

which means: "*where the factorial of ColA.ID equals the value of ColB.ID*"

My suspicion is however that someone actually meant to write `ColA.ID != ColB.ID` which is an accepted but non-standard version of the "not equal" operator and would be equivalent to `ColA.ID <> ColB.ID`

The notation `ColA.ID` suggests (as Konstantin mentioned in his answer) that those two columns are based on user-defined types which have attributes of their own (unless you simply made a an error when trying to obfuscate the real query)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like ColA and ColB are of [user defined type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-createtype.html). In Postgres you can define composite data types where one value contains multiple fields. So in your example `ColA.ID` is just field `ID` of value stored in column `ColA` of table `TableA`.

There are example [article](http://www.sqlines.com/postgresql/how-to/create_user_defined_type) for your further help.

P.S. I think `! =` is just a typographic error. It should be not equals operator